# Divide row 0 into 2 columns and keeping row 1 in 1 column. c# xaml

Tags: c#, xaml, textbox, rows

The title really says it all i would like to divide row 0 into 2 columns and keeping row 1 in 1 column.
I have some buttons, textboxes and labels at row 0, and a listbox at row 1.

But it does not seem to work. By textboxes are set to HorizontalAlignment="Stretch", and they stretch across the entire column 0-1 in row 0, and not just across column 0 in row 0.

My xaml looks like this

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="4*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="8*"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid Grid.Row="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="8"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="4"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        </Grid>

        <Button x:Name="btnFindInstaller" Content="Find installer" Click="btnFindInstaller_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="26,45,0,0" Height="30" Width="81" Background="{StaticResource ButtonDefaultColor}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
            <Button.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
                </Style>
            </Button.Resources>
        </Button>

        <Label Name="lblPath" Content="Path" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="121,45,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="36" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <TextBox Name="txtBxPath" Height="23" Margin="176,45,190,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Label Name="lblInstaller" Content="Installer" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="121,76,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="71" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <TextBox Name="txtBxInstaller" Height="23" Margin="176,75,324.6,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>

        <Button Name="btnCreateInstallData" Click="btnCreateInstallData_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="27,102,0,0" Height="40" Width="81" Background="{StaticResource ButtonDefaultColor}" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock Text="Create install data" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center" Width="62"/>
            <Button.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
                </Style>
            </Button.Resources>
        </Button>



        <Button Name="btnKillMarkedFiles"  HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="633,28,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="82" Height="40" Click="btnKillMarkedFiles_Click" Background="{StaticResource ButtonDefaultColor}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="71" VerticalAlignment="Center" TextAlignment="Center"><Run Text="Kill the "/><LineBreak/><Run/><Run Text="marked files"/></TextBlock>
            <Button.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
                </Style>
            </Button.Resources>
        </Button>
        <Button Name="btnCreatePackages" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="633,104,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="82" Height="55" Click="btnCreatePackages_Click" Background="{StaticResource ButtonDefaultColor}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0">
            <TextBlock Text="Create Installation Packages" TextWrapping="Wrap" TextAlignment="Center"/>
            <Button.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Border">
                    <Setter Property="CornerRadius" Value="10"/>
                </Style>
            </Button.Resources>
        </Button>

        <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource ButtonDefaultColor}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="4" Margin="576,73,-0.4,0" Stroke="White" VerticalAlignment="Top"  Stretch="UniformToFill" Width="186" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Label Content="Set the Killboxes" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="625,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="98" Grid.Column="0"/>
        <Rectangle Fill="{StaticResource ButtonDefaultColor}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="159" Margin="576,0,0,0" Stroke="White" VerticalAlignment="Top" Stretch="UniformToFill" Width="4"/>
        <Label Content="Repackage Plugin Installer Process" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="234" FontSize="13" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Label Content="Mark the files to packages" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="594,78,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="156" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Label Content="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="2,40,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="23" Height="37" FontSize="20" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Label Content="2" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="4,105,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="23" Height="37" FontSize="20"  Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Label Content="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="605,29,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="23" Height="37" FontSize="20"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>
        <Label Content="4" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="605,114,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="23" Height="37" FontSize="20"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"/>

        <ListBox Name="lstBoxInfoWindow" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Foreground="Black" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" Grid.Row="1">
            <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Bold"/>
                            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent"/>
                            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                        <Button Name="btnPackageVersion" Style="{StaticResource ListBoxButtonFormat}" Content ="Package version" Click="btnPackageVersion_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="10,0,10,0"/>

                        <Button Name="btnFilterPath" Style="{StaticResource ListBoxButtonFormat}" Content ="Filter path" Click="btnFilterpath_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                        <TextBlock Name="txtBlkPath" Text="{Binding path}" FontSize="10" Width="500" Height="20" Margin="10,0,10,0"/>

                        <Button Name="btnFilterfile" Style="{StaticResource ListBoxButtonFormat}" Content="Filter file" Click="btnFilterfile_Click" HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                        <TextBlock Name="txtBlkFile" Text="{Binding file}" FontSize="10" Width="150" Height="20" Margin="10,0,10,0"/>

                        <CheckBox Name="chkBxKeep" Content="Keep" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsChecked="{Binding keepKill.keep}" Margin="5,0,5,0" Checked="chkBxKeep_Checked"/>
                        <CheckBox Name="chkBxKill" Content="Kill" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right" IsChecked="{Binding keepKill.kill}" Margin="5,0,5,0" Checked="chkBxKill_Checked"/>

                        <Separator  Name="MySeparator" 
                                        Height="3"
                                        Width="Auto"
                                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                                        VerticalAlignment="Bottom"                   
                                        Background="Red" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>

    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [ColumnSpan](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.grid.columnspan?view=net-5.0) property of the `Grid`:

```
<ListBox 
      Name="lstBoxInfoWindow" 
      VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
      HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
      Foreground="Black" 
      ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" 
      Grid.Row="1"
      Grid.Column="0"
      Grid.ColumnSpan="2"
>
```

Comment: TY for you answer, but it is not the listbox which is the problem. It is the textboxes in row 0

Comment: Ahh. Is your answer to have 2 columns in both rows and then do column.span for the listbox ?

Comment: Yes, I suggest exactly this

Comment: Thanks man, that did the job... Sry im a total newb with c# and WPF

Comment: You are welcome! Please accept the answer to help people with same question in further :)